# Getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException after a Certain INPUT value

Tags: java, arrays, exception

for the Given below code after int Input Value of 46348 i am getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. I am given Condition in ***for*** loop that keeps the array limits. But somehow i am getting this exception and i unable to figure it out. And my requirement is find all primenumbers below given number.

```
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n= sc.nextInt();
    int[] arr= new int[n+1];
            for(int i=2;i<=n;i++)
            {
                if(arr[i]==0)
                {
                    for(j=i;j*i<=n;j++)
                        arr[j*i]=1; // Here i am getting Exception
                }
            }
```

Input:

46349

Output:

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -2146737495

502802

Thanks.,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have encountered an arithmetic overflow.

In Java, `int` data type is a 32-bit signed integer, which means it can have values between -2147483648 and 2147483647.

On this line:

```
for(j=i;j*i<=n;j++)
```

If `i` is 46349 then `j` becomes 46349, too. If you multiply 46349 by 46349, you get 2148229801, which is greater than 2147483647, so the integer overflows and becomes -2146737495. Naturally, it is less than 46349, so the check in the `for`-loop passes. But you cannot index an array with a negative value in Java, that's why you get the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Range check your input value for `n < 46340`, or if it really needs to work with `n = 46349` input, switch to `long` data type, which will work up to `n = 3037000499`.

Answer (score 0):

46349 * 46349 is too big to use as the index of a Java Array.  The index is just a 32-bit signed integer, so has a maximum value of 2,147,483,648.

It passes the < n check because it overflows and comes back negative, so it is in fact less than n, but a negative number is not a legal array index.