# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -2146737495

Tags: java

I have the following method:

```
public static boolean[] mk2(int n) {
    boolean[] isPrime = new boolean[n + 2];
    isPrime[1] = false;
    isPrime[2] = true;
    for (int i = 3; i <= n; i++) {
        if((i & 1) == 0) {
           isPrime[i] = false;
        } else {
           isPrime[i] = true;
        }
    }
    // cycle through to see if a number has factors other than 1 & itself
    for(int y = 3; y <= n; y++) {
        System.out.print("Test y " + y);
        if(isPrime[y]) {
            for(int i = 2; i <= y-1; i++) {
                if(y%i==0){
                    // stop here if it isn't prime
                    isPrime[y] = false;
                    System.out.println(" disproved");
                    i = y + 1;
                }     
            }
            if(isPrime[y]){
                    System.out.println(" is prime and disproves:");
                    for (int j = y; y*j <= n; j++) {
                        if(y*j<=n) {
                            isPrime[y*j] = false;
                            System.out.print(" "+(y*j)+" ");
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println(".");
                }
        } else {
            System.out.println(" already disproved");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Primes");
    int x = 0;
    for(int i=1; i <= n; i++) {
        if(isPrime[i]) {
            System.out.print(i+", ");
            x++;
        }
        if(x >= 61) {
            System.out.println(";");
            x = 0;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(".");

    return isPrime;
}
```

which generally works fine but when I set n to 100000 I get the following exception `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -2146737495`

from what I have been able to find `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` normally occurs when you try to access a point in the array greater than its defined size e.g.

```
int[] x = new int[5];
x[10] = 2;
```

so I am a bit confused as to what is happening here.
Any Ideas?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through it with a debugger to see when it over-subscripts the array?

Comment: an index should be positive :)

Comment: Your logic is a bit hard to follow, but I don't see where you're using the first element, e.g. isPrime[0]. And in one loop you have the control statement as a `<=` which will generally over-subscript your array. You usually want just `<`.

Comment: the last thing show in the terminal Is `Test y 46347 already disproved`
`Test y 46348 already disproved`
`Test y 46349 is prime and disproves:`
`    Exception occurred.` so I'm assuming it goes wrong around their but as the array is set to n + 2 and I check whether y*j is greater than n so i'm not sure how its happening

Comment: Two words: **prior research** (really really easy to resolve without asking a new question); and **overflow**. OK, so that's more than two words; but still the essence of what matters in the context of your question.

Comment: @Stefan Beike i don't see where it went negative

Comment: the exception told you it is negative. the answer from @Mena is a good approach.

Comment: This question seems related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11202276/getting-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-after-a-certain-input-value

Comment: Just an FYI, Java Arrays are 0 based, meaning the first element of your array will be in isPrime[0]

Comment: The if statement checking that `y*j <= n` inside your for loop, which checks that `y*j <= n` is pointless. You should actually be checking that `y*j <= n && y*j > 0`. This will avoid your error. You don't need to and shouldn't change anything to `long` unless `n` itself is `long`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error very likely comes from an arithmetic overflow of `int`.

The most likely root cause is your reference to element `isPrime[y*j]`, where `y * j` overflows the `int` and returns `Integer.MIN_VALUE + (the amount overflown - 1)`.

You should set a breakpoint and debug those values.

Comment: Didn't think of that. how would i set it long?

Comment: @AlexanderBrown you can use `long` in `for` loops. Beware though, it's likely that you don't want to use arrays with such large numbers of elements (see `OutOfMemoryError`s) and there might be a genuine bug in the code. Debug first is my advice.

Comment: I have found its trying to do `46349*46349` which is  greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` but is also bigger than n which shouldn't be happening

Comment: @AlexanderBrown yeah i suspected it would be a functional bug :)

Comment: found the problem! I setting `j = y` instead of `j = 2` making my results dodgy and causing the calculation to exceed `Integer.MAX_VALUE`

Comment: @AlexanderBrown nice :)

Answer (score 1):

The problematic statement is `isPrime[y*j] = false;` which is generating a number outside of `Integer` range. Once it reach maximum number and start from negitive numbers, and you get the exception because the index should be `>= 0 and < len`

More specifically you are trying to multiply `y= 46349, j=46349` which results in `2148229801` which is greater then `Integer.MAX_VALUE=2147483647`

Answer (score 0):

> When integer overflows, it goes back to the minimum value and
>   continues from there. If it underflows, it goes back to the maximum
>   value and continues from there.

So According to

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -2146737495
```

Because index must be positive :

According java language specification :

> All array accesses are checked at run time; an attempt to use an index
>   that is less than zero or greater than or equal to the length of the
>   array causes an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException to be thrown.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13

Comment: but where does it go negative? i would understand if i had gone too high but their shouldn't be any negatives

Answer (score 0):

The int is 32-bit and long is 64-bit.  So it provides a bigger range.  What you should do is convert variables j and y to longs:

```
for(long y = 3; y <= n; y++) {

for (long j = y; y*j <= n; j++) {
```

And wherever you index an array, you need to convert it to an

```
if(isPrime[(int)y]) {
```

What's happening is that you're multiplying two ints which exceed the int range and it thus becomes negative and the condition below satisfies as true:

```
if(y*j<=n) {
```

and then it is trying to assign to some negative index in your array:

```
    isPrime[y*j] = false;
```